# encode string with base 64 returns empty or null in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, encoding, base64

I am trying to prepare url, in which email address will be base64 encoded. However when I encode the email with base64 it returns emptry string, without base64 encode this works fine, what am I missing here?

here is shell script without base64  encode

```
#!/bin/bash

link='unsubscribe'
testVar="$link/""me@domain.com"
echo "www.somedomain.com/$testVar/email/"
```

Output:

```
www.somedomain.com/unsubscribe/me@domain/email/
```

I am trying to encode email with base64 like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

link='unsubscribe'
testVar="$link/""me@domain.com"|base64
echo "www.somedomain.com/$testVar/email/"
```

Output

```
www.somedomain.com/unsubscribe//email/
```

Notice the email did not get encoded, returned empty value

what I am missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not *passing* the string contained in the variable `test` to `base64` command, use [Command substitution $(..)](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst) syntax to pass the string without newline to the command, using `printf`

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

link='unsubscribe'
test=$(printf "%s" "$link/""me@domain.com" | base64)
echo "www.somedomain.com/${test}/email/"
```

produces an output as

```
www.somedomain.com/dW5zdWJzY3JpYmUvbWVAZG9tYWluLmNvbQ==/email/
```

---

Not relevant to your actual question, but I think as a general coding guideline, you should *not* name variables as `test`, as this can be easily confused with the [`test` operator in `bash`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest). Would be good if you can add more context to what purpose the variable is used for, may be `testVar`, `testStr` or `testRef`.

Comment: or just `echo "www.somedomain.com/$(base64 <<< "$link/me@domain.com")/email/"` would be sufficient.

Comment: @123: If am not wrong, here-string, creates a new-line after the string, just like `echo`, try `hexdump -c <<< "Hello World"`. Compare it with just `hexdump -c < <( printf "%s" "Hello World" )`. Hence your command might produce a different md5 string including the `\n`

Comment: Whoops, yeah your right, the point of the comment was that you could use command sub directly in the echo.

Comment: @Inian yes agreed to your comment related to naming variables properly, for asking question purpose I submitted the pseudo code, even then naming should have been proper, agreed :) thanks for your help, made edits in my question